# How do I send a picture SMS?

Tags: c#, sms, image

How do I convert a 32x16 pixel image to a picture SMS message?

I already have the code needed to send normal text SMS, but am looking for help with sending picture SMS.

Comment: How are you sending the SMS, is itthrough a 3rd party gateway?

Comment: Do you mean sending an MMS? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Converting image files to OTA file format](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ota_converter.aspx). The code is in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the binary image format to a format (e.g. base64) that can be transferred following the SMS specifications for content streams. The SMS specification imposes some limits on the length of a single message ([140 octets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size)) and your picture really has to be smaller. Otherwise, this'll be transported as a series of SMSs which you'll need to pull together on the receiving end.